# The Extention appeared in the backend but the database is not installed

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, sql

i have installed manually an extension through ftp and it appeared at the back end of magento but it showed error that there is no database,so i create the database through file called install.php that is found in the files of extetion and it start to work but certain feature is not working like it should and i am sure that is because there is wrong with the database because i didnit understand everything in install.php file could anyone teach me how to install the database like to convert the php to SQL ?

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is part of the "Easy Shipping Rules" module for Magento eCommerce
 * developed by (c) Matheus Gontijo <matheus@matheusgontijo.com>
 */

/**
 * Installer
 *
 * @category    MatheusGontijo
 * @package     MatheusGontijo_EasyShippingRules
 * @author      Matheus Gontijo <matheus@matheusgontijo.com>
 * @license     OSL v3.0
 */

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_carrier'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/carrier'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_carrier_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary'  => true,
    ), 'Carrier ID')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Name')
    ->addColumn('is_active', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, 6, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => 0,
    ), 'Is Active')
    ->addColumn('position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, 6, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => 0,
    ), 'Position')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Created At')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Updated At')
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Carrier');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_custom_method'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/custom_method'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary'  => true,
    ), 'Custom Method ID')
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_carrier_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Custom Method ID')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Name')
    ->addColumn('is_active', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, 6, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'    => 0,
    ), 'Is Active')
    ->addColumn('price_action', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Price Action')
    ->addColumn('price_percentage', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,2', array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Price or Percentage')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Created At')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Updated At')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/carrier', array('easyshippingrules_carrier_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_carrier_id')
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/custom_method', 'easyshippingrules_carrier_id', 'easyshippingrules/carrier', 'easyshippingrules_carrier_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_carrier_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/carrier'),
        'easyshippingrules_carrier_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_SET_NULL,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_SET_NULL
    )
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Custom Method');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_store'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/custom_method_store'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ), 'Custom Method ID')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => '0',
    ), 'Store ID')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_store', array('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id')
    )
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_store', array('store_id')),
        array('store_id')
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_store', 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id', 'easyshippingrules/custom_method', 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/custom_method'),
        'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_store', 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
        'store_id',
        $installer->getTable('core/store'),
        'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Custom Method');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_carrier'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/custom_method_carrier'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_carrier_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ), 'Carrier ID')
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ), 'Custom Method ID')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/custom_method', array('easyshippingrules_carrier_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_carrier_id')
    )
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/custom_method', array('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id')
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_carrier', 'easyshippingrules_carrier_id', 'easyshippingrules/carrier', 'easyshippingrules_carrier_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_carrier_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/carrier'),
        'easyshippingrules_carrier_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_carrier', 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id', 'easyshippingrules/custom_method', 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/custom_method'),
        'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Custom Method');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_existing_method'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/existing_method'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_existing_method_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary'  => true,
    ), 'Existing Method ID')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Name')
    ->addColumn('carrier_name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Carrier Name')
    ->addColumn('method_name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Method Name')
    ->addColumn('is_active', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, 6, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => 0,
    ), 'Is Active')
    ->addColumn('action', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Action')
    ->addColumn('price_action', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Price Action')
    ->addColumn('price_percentage', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,2', array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Price or Percentage')
    ->addColumn('shipping_method_codes', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 255, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Shipping Method Codes')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Created At')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Updated At')
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Existing Method');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_existing_method_store'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/existing_method_store'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_existing_method_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ), 'Existing Method ID')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => '0',
    ), 'Store ID')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/existing_method_store', array('easyshippingrules_existing_method_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_existing_method_id')
    )
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/existing_method_store', array('store_id')),
        array('store_id')
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/existing_method_store', 'easyshippingrules_existing_method_id', 'easyshippingrules/existing_method', 'easyshippingrules_existing_method_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_existing_method_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/existing_method'),
        'easyshippingrules_existing_method_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/existing_method_store', 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
        'store_id',
        $installer->getTable('core/store'),
        'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Existing Method');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_rule'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/rule'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_rule_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary'  => true,
    ), 'Rule ID')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 50, array(
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Name')
    ->addColumn('description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Description')
    ->addColumn('conditions_serialized', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable' => false,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Conditions Serialized')
    ->addColumn('price_percentage', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,2', array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Price or Percentage')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Created At')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Updated At')
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Rule');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_rule'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/custom_method_rule'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ), 'Custom Method ID')
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_rule_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ), 'Store ID')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_rule', array('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_custom_method_id')
    )
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_rule', array('easyshippingrules_rule_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_rule_id')
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_rule', 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id', 'easyshippingrules/custom_method', 'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/custom_method'),
        'easyshippingrules_custom_method_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/custom_method_rule', 'easyshippingrules_rule_id', 'easyshippingrules/rule', 'easyshippingrules_rule_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_rule_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/rule'),
        'easyshippingrules_rule_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Custom Method');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'easyshippingrules_existing_method_rule'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/existing_method_rule'))
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_existing_method_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ), 'Existing Method ID')
    ->addColumn('easyshippingrules_rule_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'primary'  => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ), 'Store ID')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/existing_method_rule', array('easyshippingrules_existing_method_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_existing_method_id')
    )
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('easyshippingrules/existing_method_rule', array('easyshippingrules_rule_id')),
        array('easyshippingrules_rule_id')
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/existing_method_rule', 'easyshippingrules_existing_method_id', 'easyshippingrules/existing_method', 'easyshippingrules_existing_method_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_existing_method_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/existing_method'),
        'easyshippingrules_existing_method_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName('easyshippingrules/existing_method_rule', 'easyshippingrules_rule_id', 'easyshippingrules/rule', 'easyshippingrules_rule_id'),
        'easyshippingrules_rule_id',
        $installer->getTable('easyshippingrules/rule'),
        'easyshippingrules_rule_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->setComment('Easy Shipping Rules - Existing Method');

$installer
    ->getConnection()
    ->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you install any extension in magento, you should make sure you upload each and every files in right directories.

All `sql` related files should go to `Extension_pack/Extension_name/sql` folder.

And extension also depends upon all other blocks, models, helpers, controllers file as well as design files.

I would suggest you to check every files and folder again.

If you have need to tell your magento to re-install all again, do this

1. First, make sure all files and folders of extensions are correctly uploaded.
2. Now go to database and find 'core_resource' table and inside that find your extension's setup name (setup name can be found from `etc/config.xml` file) and delete.
3. Then clear cache and log out and login again.

Before doing this, I would recommend to make backup of database.

Good luck.

Comment: ok so for the sql file (install.php) is located in the Extension_pack/Extension_name/sql/Extention_Setup/install.php 
is that right or i should move it to the Extension_pack/Extension_name/sql?
i appreciate your answer

Comment: That is in right place. No need to change.

Comment: when i delete the setup name of the extention the site show me blank page for admin and frontend, i re add the table manually and the site came back but with the same probleme, is there any way that i could install the table from the install.php files manualy because i only have one table with wrong configuration

Comment: Do step no. 2, it will install all again.

Comment: i did that like i told you and the site go down

Comment: just one more think, i put the install.php file at the root and tried to access it through the url but it showed me blank page

Comment: where did you delete? did you from `core_resource` table?

Comment: yes, by the way i create the tables manually and now the site is working with the extension at the backend and save the rules and options but it is not reflecting on the front end although i disabled the cash and clear it and using incognito tab to make sure no cash or cookies

Comment: You should check how to install extension from ftp. It's hard to say what's going on and what have you done. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for your patient just to make it clear for other who is willing to answer me that i have install the extention through ftp